# what's the meaning of this instructions(subl $20, %esp)?

Tags: c, assembly

The C codes is:

```
int rSum(int *Start, int Count)
{
        if (Count <= 0)
        return 0;
        return *Start + rSum(Start+1, Count-1);
}
```

the corresponding Assemble codes is:

```
.file "test98.c"
.text
.globl rSum
.type rSum, @function
rSum:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
pushl %ebx
subl $20, %esp
cmpl $0, 12(%ebp)
jg .L2
movl $0, %eax
jmp .L3
.L2:
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
movl (%eax), %ebx
movl 12(%ebp), %eax
leal -1(%eax), %edx
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
addl $4, %eax
movl %edx, 4(%esp)
movl %eax, (%esp)
call rSum
leal (%ebx,%eax), %eax
.L3:
addl $20, %esp
popl %ebx
popl %ebp
ret
.size rSum, .-rSum
.ident "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"
.section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I can't understand this instrutions "subl $20, %esp", and Why is $20 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`subl $20, %esp` subtracts 20 from the stack pointer (`esp`). This allocates 20 bytes of space on the stack that can be used for local variables.

Comment: Thank you,and Why is $20 , not $30, $40?

Comment: @lxgeek: If you're asking why 32, it's because that's how much space the compiler decided was necessary to store the local variables.

Comment: For GAS/AT&T, `$` indicates that it's the immediate value 20 and not the value at address 20. It's not hexadecimal. Those 20 bytes of space would be 8 bytes for the arguments needed to call `rsum` and not local variables. The remaining 12 bytes are unnecessary, but the compiler may have felt like doing that just to maintain a 64-byte aligned stack (in case of any SSE).

Comment: @Brendan: SSE only needs 16-byte alignment, which the 12 bytes wasted gives.

Comment: @Brendan: Oh, excuse me. It was a guess; I'm really only familiar with Intel syntax.

Comment: @icktoofay: No, its not hexidecimal -- its decimal 20.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, I fixed it. I was unfamiliar with AT&T syntax and made an (incorrect) guess.